# How would you compare the names in a list to ones in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, api, compare

I have a list of movies and I want to compare to the Array of movies i got from Facebook Graph API.

Here is an example of what API is getting:

```
{"data": [
  {
     "name": "The Drift Bible",
     "category": "Movie",
     "id": "227431881228",
     "created_time": "2011-02-27T21:41:04+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Shooter",
     "category": "Movie",
     "id": "109671005718938",
     "created_time": "2011-02-16T09:18:29+0000"
  }...
```

The list I need to compare is pretty big, but here are some:

```
Wall Street, Shooter, Young Guns, Due Date...
```

Basically just compare 'Name' in 'data' with 'my list' of Movie titles. But can't figure out the syntax

Something like:

```
if ($movies->data->name == 'movie titles list') {echo "You like the same movies";}
```

I found this:

```
if (in_array('movie titles list', $a)) {echo "You like the same movies";}
```

Any thoughts would help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data looks to be JSON encoded...

Try something like this: ([json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

```
$large_data = '{"data": [
  {
     "name": "The Drift Bible",
     "category": "Movie",
     "id": "227431881228",
     "created_time": "2011-02-27T21:41:04+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Shooter",
     "category": "Movie",
     "id": "109671005718938",
     "created_time": "2011-02-16T09:18:29+0000"
  }]}';

$json_to_array = json_decode($large_data, true);
var_dump(json_decode($large_data, true));    

// You should now be able to compare the two array
echo print_r($json_to_array,true);
```

EDIT:

Improving on what @Eric posted

```
$large_data = '{"data": [
  {
     "name": "The Drift Bible",
     "category": "Movie",
     "id": "227431881228",
     "created_time": "2011-02-27T21:41:04+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "Shooter",
     "category": "Movie",
     "id": "109671005718938",
     "created_time": "2011-02-16T09:18:29+0000"
  }]}';

$movie_list = json_decode($large_data, true);
$movieNames = array();
foreach($movie_list as $movies) {
    foreach($movies as $movie) {
        $movieNames[] = $movie['name'];
    }
}

$myMovies = array('Wall Street', 'Shooter', 'Young Guns', 'Due Date');

$common_movies = array_intersect($movieNames, $myMovies);

foreach($common_movies as $common_movie) {
    echo "We like the same movie ".$common_movie."<br />\n";    
}
```

Comment: well if i do a var_dump i get: object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["data"]=> array(18) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["name"]=> string(15) "The Drift Bible" ["category"]=> string(5) "Movie" ["id"]=> string(12) "227431881228" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2011-02-27T21:41:04+0000" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Shooter" ["category"]=> string(5) "Movie" ["id"]=> string(15) "109671005718938" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2011-02-16T09:18:29+0000" }

Comment: May want to check your variables and closing braces.

Comment: sry was just going off the data her posted in the example, should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_intersect(array1, array2, ... arrayN)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$large_data = '{"data": [
    {
        "name": "The Drift Bible",
        "category": "Movie",
        "id": "227431881228",
        "created_time": "2011-02-27T21:41:04+0000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Shooter",
        "category": "Movie",
        "id": "109671005718938",
        "created_time": "2011-02-16T09:18:29+0000"
    }
]}';

$movies = json_decode($large_data, true)['data'];
$movieNames = array();

//Get only the name from the movie list
foreach($movies as $movie) {
    $movieNames[] = $movie['name'];
}

//Intersect with internal list
print_r(array_intersect($movieNames, $myMovies));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
<?php
    $json_data = '{"data": [
        {
           "name": "The Drift Bible",
           "category": "Movie",
           "id": "227431881228",
           "created_time": "2011-02-27T21:41:04+0000"
        },
        {
           "name": "Shooter",
           "category": "Movie",
           "id": "109671005718938",
           "created_time": "2011-02-16T09:18:29+0000"
        }
        ]}';

    $array_data = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);

    $compare_list = array(
        'Wall Street',
        'Shooter',
        'Young Guns',
        'Due Date'
    );

    // <Marco Stumper> phpundhtml at web dot de
    function in_array_multi($needle, $haystack) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($haystack as $value) {
            if ((is_array($value) && in_array_multi($needle, $value)) || $value == $needle) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        return $found;
    }

    foreach ($compare_list as $item) {
        echo '<p>' . $item . (in_array_multi($item, $array_data) ? ' DOES ' : ' does NOT ') . 'exist within $array_data</p>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Wall Street does NOT exist within $array_data</p>
<p>Shooter DOES exist within $array_data</p>
<p>Young Guns does NOT exist within $array_data</p>
<p>Due Date does NOT exist within $array_data</p>
```